# Larvel querying relationship existence still returns empty records

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm working in a Laravel 9 project and need to show only records where the deeply nested relationship has records, in my case, `tiers`.

My relationship right now is still returning me `pingtree_entries` even though `tiers` are empty, what am I missing?

Here's my top level query:

```php
$pingtree = Pingtree::where('company_id', $company_id)
                    ->where('id', $id)
                    ->has('pingtree_entries.tiers')
                    ->with('pingtree_entries.tiers')
                    ->first();
```

This should be saying something like:

> Get me my `Pingtree` by company ID and ID with my tiers associated to the pingtree_entries for the Pingtrees where there is more than 0 tiers.

My **Pingtree** model defines:

```php
/**
 * Get the pingtrees that the model has.
 */
public function pingtree_entries()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PingtreeEntry::class);
}
```

My **PingtreeEntry** model defines:

```php
/**
 * Get the buyer tier that the model has.
 */
public function tiers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BuyerTier::class, 'id', 'buyer_tier_id');
}
```

This is outputting the following via Postman:

```json
{
    "model": {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "company_id": 1,
        "pick_chance": 4,
        "name": "omnis iusto consequatur",
        "description": "Hic nihil suscipit error.",
        "is_enabled": false,
        "created_at": "2023-01-27T14:15:26.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-01-27T14:15:26.000000Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "is_deleting": false,
        "pingtree_entries": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "user_id": 1,
                "company_id": 1,
                "buyer_id": 2,
                "buyer_tier_id": 4,
                "pingtree_id": 1,
                "pingtree_group_id": null,
                "processing_order": 1,
                "is_enabled": true,
                "created_at": "2023-01-27T14:15:26.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-01-27T14:15:26.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "tiers": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "user_id": 1,
                        "company_id": 1,
                        "buyer_id": 2,
                        "country_id": 2,
                        "product_id": 3,
                        "name": "dignissimos voluptas et",
                        "description": "Dolore tempora et maxime nam.",
                        "processing_class": "et",
                        "is_default": false,
                        "is_enabled": false,
                        "created_at": "2023-01-27T14:15:25.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2023-01-27T14:15:25.000000Z",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "is_deleting": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "user_id": 1,
                "company_id": 1,
                "buyer_id": null,
                "buyer_tier_id": null,
                "pingtree_id": 1,
                "pingtree_group_id": 1,
                "processing_order": 1,
                "is_enabled": false,
                "created_at": "2023-01-27T14:15:26.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-01-27T14:15:26.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "tiers": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Note that the last `PingtreeEntry` has no tiers. So I don't want to show the whole `PingtreeEntry` model at all.

Attempted with `whereHas`

```php
$pingtree = Pingtree::where('company_id', $company_id)
                    ->where('id', $id)
                    ->whereHas('pingtree_entries.tiers')
                    ->with('pingtree_entries.tiers.buyer')
                    ->first();
```

Comment: use whereHas() which instead of has()

Comment: `->whereHas('pingtree_entries.tier')` added to the `Pingtree` model still returns the parent model with empty tiers.

Comment: please add your code here with whereHas condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use :

```
$pingtree = Pingtree::where('company_id', $company_id)
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->with([
            'pingtree_entries' => fn($q) => $q->has('tiers'),
            'pingtree_entries.tiers',
        ])
        ->first();
```